# Finding the string has max length in a list with syntax "for(Type varName:list)"

Tags: java, compare

i already wrote codes to examine a string has max length in a list like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MaxLength {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        ArrayList<String> mylist= new ArrayList <>(Arrays.asList("abc","Hello","young","12345"));
        System.out.println(max(mylist));
    }
    public static String max(ArrayList <String> list){
        String a= "";
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i=i+1){
            if(list.get(i).length()>=a.length()){
                a=list.get(i);
                for(String si:list){System.out.println(si);}
            }
        }

        return a;} 
}
```

Now I want to use `for(Type varName:list)` in order to iterate
on the elements ignoring the index and rewrite the max function.How should it be written to compare elements without using index? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java != Javascript

Comment: please don't misuse the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already been using the same thing said by your teacher, which is

```
   for (String si : list) {
                    System.out.println(si);
        }
```

And if you do the same with top loop,

```
public static String max(ArrayList<String> list) {
        String a = "";
        for (String string : list) {
            if (string.length() >= a.length()) {
                a = string;
                for (String si : list) {
                    System.out.println(si);
                }
            }

        }
        return a;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply as you used for in the other Loop:

```
        for (String s : list) {
            if(s.length()>=a.length()){
                a=s;
                for(String si:list){System.out.println(si);}
            }
        }
```